# How to correctly jump to source from PyCharm pytest test explorer?

Tags: pycharm, pytest, test-explorer

I tried to jump to a file shown in `pytest text explorer` by double clicking on the name of a test function in the tree view of the test explorer (I use PyCharm 2023.1.1, Community Edition):

[image]

However, instead of opening the corresponding file in the editor:

```
{project_root}/back_end/test/test_fuel_split.py
```

PyCharm jumps to a wrong location:

```
External Libraries => Python 3.10.5 => Lib => test
```

How can I fix that? Is there some PyCharm or pytest configuration I need to adapt? Or is this a PyCharm bug?

Comment: I am having exact same issue, were you able to fix it ?

Comment: There is an open bug: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-47727/Pycharm-goes-to-the-wrong-test-when-using-pytest-When-having-several-packages-under-same-parent

Answer (score 0):

You will need to mark the `tests` folder as test sources in PyCharm in `Preferences > Project Structure`. They should appear green in the project explorer once this is configured correctly.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. a) That option is not available for me in PyCharm Community Edition 2023.1.1. Also see intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/… b) Applying the mentioned work around using the settings file, the test folder turns green. Nevertheless, double clicking on the name of a test function in the test explorer still navigates to a wrong target location.

Comment: This does not work.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was to set a working directory in the pytest configration template to the places where my automation is located. Clear all previous configs add the directory and run again the test:
[Pytest config template](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tm77I.png)